# Custom directive not recognized

Tags: angular

I've created a custom directive called holdable.

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, Output, HostListener,  } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable, Subject, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil, tap, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHoldable]'
})
export class HoldableDirective {

  @Output() holdTime: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();

  state: Subject<string> = new Subject();

  cancel: Observable<string>;

  constructor() { 
    this.cancel = this.state.pipe(
      filter(v => v === 'cancel'),
      tap(v => {
        console.log('Stopped holding.');
        this.holdTime.emit(0);
      }
      )
    );
  }

  @HostListener('mouseup', ['$event'])
  @HostListener('mouseleave', ['$event'])
  onExit(){
    this.state.next('cancel');
  }

  @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
  onHold(){
    console.log('Started holding.');
    this.state.next('start');
    const n = 100;
    interval(n).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.cancel),
      tap(v => {
        this.holdTime.emit(v * n);
      })
    )
    .subscribe()
  }
}
```

It it registered in the AppModule, because I want to use it in the Overall application. For example in my module called CashRegisterModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { CashRegisterRoutingModule } from './cash-register-routing.module';

import { CashRegisterComponent } from './cash-register.component';
import { UIModule } from '../UI/ui.module';
import { ScannerComponent } from './steps/scanner/scanner.component';
import { ArticlePreviewComponent } from './steps/article-preview/article-preview.component';
import { OverviewComponent } from './steps/overview/overview.component';
import { PaymentComponent } from './steps/payment/payment.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CashRegisterComponent, 
    ScannerComponent, 
    ArticlePreviewComponent, OverviewComponent, PaymentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CashRegisterRoutingModule,
    UIModule
  ]
})
export class CashRegisterModule { }
```

And this module is also registered in the app.module.ts file Looking like this

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { DashboardModule } from './views/dashboard/dashboard.module';
import { UIModule } from './UI/ui.module';
import { ArticleModule } from './views/article/article.module';
import { ArticleService } from './services/article.service';
import { UiService } from './services/ui.service';
import { CashRegisterModule } from './cash-register/cash-register.module';
import { DataService } from './services/data.service';
import { HoldableDirective } from './directives/holdable.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HoldableDirective,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    DashboardModule,
    UIModule,
    ArticleModule,
    CashRegisterModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ArticleService,
    UiService,
    DataService
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ],

})
export class AppModule { }
```

I use the directive in the button inside the PaymentComponent of the CashRegisterComponent

```
<button *ngFor="let moneyType of state.moneyToRender"
      appHoldable (holdTime)="calculateGivenMoney(moneyType, $event)"
      >{{moneyType.toFixed(2)}} €
    </button>
```

calculateGivenMoney(…) will be initialized like so

```
calculateGivenMoney(amount: number, /*operation: string,*/ holdTime: number): number {
    console.log('ich werde geklickt.' + holdTime)
    if(holdTime > 1000){
      this.state.givenMoney = this.state.givenMoney - amount;
    } else {
      this.state.givenMoney = this.state.givenMoney + amount;
    } return this.state.givenMoney;
}
```

But neither of the print Statements are working…

Does anyone know what isn't working inside my Code?

Thank you very much for your help and have a nice day!

Comment: To use the directives within an individual module, you need to import or declare in each module.

Comment: Are there any errors in your console??

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52640419/cant-use-directive-declared-inside-app-module-in-child-modules-in-angular-6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three steps to get this working. And it applies to almost all Angular elements like components, directives, pipes etc.

1. Declare the directive in a particular module Eg: `SharedModule`
2. Export the directive from that module i.e `SharedModule`
3. Import the module in the parent module of the component where you want to use it. Eg: `SomeOtherModule`

Example code:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [HoldableDirective],
    exports: [HoldableDirective]
})
export class SharedModule {}


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        SomeChildComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        ... other modules,
        SharedModule
    ]
})
export class SomeOtherModule
```

This way the directive with its respective selector will be available to all members of `SomeOtherModule`.

> Note: It is important to export module members if you want them to be
>   accessible from other modules. Think of it like a public API for the
>   module.

Comment: Alright thank you very much for that great Explanation. So I will declare it specifically within the module I Need it Right now. But if I want to Access this directive in every module Right now and in the future, is that not possible when I declare directives directly in the "app root module"? Do I Always have to Import it everywhere I Need it and can this step not be simplified through declaring it in the app root module where every other module is importet too?

Comment: Modules in Angular are somewhat similar to packages in other languages. `Basically they are a logical grouping of various angular elements.` As you mentioned that you need to access the directive in every module. It's best to create a module named `SharedModule` and declare and export all commonly used features under it. Then you only need to import the `SharedModule` in all other modules. https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules#sharing-modules and https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#shared-feature-module are good reads.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are thinking of how `providers` work in modules, kind of a "top down" approach where any module down stream of the module with the provider can use it.

To use components or directives within an individual module, they need to be imported or declared in that individual module. My preference is to create a module for that directive or smaller groups of functionality, export the reusable pieces, and import them where they are needed (see the [Angular Material library](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/lib) for an example).

Using that with your example:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HoldableDirective,
  ],
  exports: [
    HoldableDirective,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ...
  ]
})
export class HoldableModule { }


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CashRegisterComponent, 
    ScannerComponent, 
    ArticlePreviewComponent, OverviewComponent, PaymentComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CashRegisterRoutingModule,
    UIModule,
    HoldableModule, // <-- useing that common module here

  ]
})
export class CashRegisterModule { }
```

Comment: Okay thank you very much! So than I will follow the Approach to integrate creating a shared module into my workflow, where I define all functionality I will Need in the Overall application! Thank you very much!